# how to print shipping options in cartthrob

Tags: cartthrob, shipping

I am using the flat rates shipping plugin in cartthrob. I need to add a description for the shipping product, so I managed to get this far:

I added the following in cartthrob_shipping_flat_rates.php

```
            array(
                'name' => 'shipping_product_description',
                'short_name' => 'product_description',
                'type' => 'text'
            ),
```

This code added the fields I need to input a description to each shipping product i.e.(arrives within 7-14 days, arrives within 3 days etc.).

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1348309/shipping.png

My question is, how do I make use of that content. In my template tags I am using the following:

```
<h3>{rate_title} Shipping</h3>
<h5>{product_description}</h5>
```

and this is outputting this:

USPS Priority Shipping
{product_description}

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1348309/shipping-template.png

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to return this extra information back to the template through a tag. Creating the new settings array as you have done will only store the information against your plugin, not automatically return it to the template.

I haven't tested this, but here's what I *think* you'd need to add to the plugin.

In the `initialize()` function, around line 59 you should see:

```
$this->rate_titles[$rate['short_name']] = $rate['title'];
```

Add:

```
$this->product_description[$rate['short_name']] = $rate['product_description'];
```

You should then be able to create a new tag variable in the `plugin_shipping_options()` function towards the end of the plugin.

```
public function plugin_shipping_options()
{
    $options = array();

    foreach ($this->rates as $rate_short_name => $price)
    {
        $options[] = array(
            'rate_short_name' => $rate_short_name,
            'price' => $price,
            'rate_price' => $price,
            'rate_title' => $this->rate_titles[$rate_short_name],
            'product_description' => $this->rate_titles[$product_description]
        );
    }

    return $options;
}
```

You should then have access to the tag `{product_description}` in your template. As I said, not tested this so can't be sure it would work.

Also, I'd recommend changing your tag to something like `shipping_rate_description` to avoid any potential confusion with any channel entries tags that might be of a similar name.